# MacBook EFI, no sound. Convert to hybrid GBT/MBR?

Tags: windows-10, bios, macbook, efi

I only use Windows on my MacBook. So I made a clean installation of Windows without dual-booting OSX. This installation resulted in the Mac is now booting in EFI mode, which led to the sound and ThunderPort not working.

I've googled around trying to look for solutions to this problem, and it seems that I have to convert my boot mode from EFI to Legacy OS (emulated BIOS)?

Can I convert my current Windows installation (GPT with EFI boot) to boot in Legacy OS (hybrid GPT/MBR)? If so, how?

Comment: No. You cannot. What exactly is your Hardware?

Comment: Early 2011 MBP.

Comment: I tried quite a lot with my MBA mid 2011. most problems came with built in Intel HD 3000 graphics and integrated sound. for some unknown reasons the MBA behaved much better when installed with legacy BIOS emulation. But still some issues Wifi interface consuming too much CPU. Did you try clean EFI install with the latest Slow Ring Build?

Comment: Yeah it was a new and clean EFI install. I ended up reinstalling everything from a disc instead, so it boots in emulated BIOS.

Comment: Is your Macbook listed as officially win10-supported by apple? btw: how long is your device waiting in BIOS before it actually starts to boot windows?

Comment: I don't think it's officialy supported. It takes It takes a couple of seconds for it to hit the Windows boot logo, there is no BIOS as such.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 support UEFI booting. Try to use disk utility, create a FAT partition in your hard drive. Then use fdisk to remove hybrid mbr on this hardrive. Then use windows 10 installer FOR GPT PARTITION SCHEM : A windows that can be installed to boot from UEFI (efi is almost the same). Then in this installer, just turn your FAT partition to NTFS, and install windows as normal.
I did so, my windows 8.1 is booting from EFI. It's working for windows up to 7 I don't know if windows 7 have an UEFI support.